# How to implement patch requests in RESTEasy?

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I would like to implement multiple operations in one Patch request (json format). RESTEasy doesn't support Patch requests out-of-box. How to provide custom implementation?

Answer (score 12):

To enable `PATCH` you need to define a annotation annotated with [@HttpMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/HttpMethod.html):

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@HttpMethod("PATCH")
public @interface PATCH {}
```

A full example is described in Bill Burke's book "RESTful Java with JAX-RS 2.0". The sourcecode can be found in the [resteasy repository](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/tree/master/jaxrs/examples/oreilly-jaxrs-2.0-workbook/ex04_1).

Maybe JAX-RS 2.1. will [support PATCH out of the box](https://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec/lists/users/archive/2015-11/message/1).

**Update:** If you want to patch multiple resources in one request you need to identify them first. For instance if you want to give all customers with a certain turnover the VIP status you could have a resource-method like this:

```java
@PATCH
@Path("/customers")
public Response patchCustomers(@QueryParam("minTurnover") Double minTurnover, InputStream is) {
   // find and update customers
}
```

Which information is passed in the entity body is up to you. The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) demands "a set of changes" which should be applied to the resource. This could be simple `text/plain` like `update: vip=true`.
A standard-format for such updates is [json-patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902):

```
PATCH /customers?minTurnover=1000 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json-patch

[
  { 
    "op" : "replace", 
    "path" : "/vip", 
    "value" : "true" 
  },
  {
    ... more operations ...
  }
]
```

Note that the same set of operations should be applied to all identified resources.

Comment: Thanks for giving pointers. This implementation is talks about if the request contains only one update. But, I am looking for implementation of a single request contains multiple updates, that may related to different Resources. I can implement in way that parse the input stream in a Common resource and make sequential calls to other resource. But its not elegant solution. I am thinking, a filter/interceptor does the parsing and create/spawn multiple requests. All should run parallel.

Comment: I updated the answer. Note that what happens in the resource class is not JAX-RS related. You could do plain sql-updates or trigger a batch-job which does this with high parallelization. This is nothing the client should decide. He just tells in one request which resources should be updated.

Comment: I am looking for solution, if multiple operations are with different paths.

Comment: The path identifies the resource(s) and a HTTP request uses only one. `GET /customers/4711` returns customer 4711 and not customer 0815 or product 1313. Same with `PATCH`: If you want to update e.g. /customers and /products your client needs to make two calls.

Comment: I am not sure whether it's a good practice, but 'path' attribute accepts nested paths, so you could imagine making a PATCH request on /customers resource and having multiple operations referring to multiple customers.

Comment: Until one can use the JAX-RS 2.1, one can read https://craftsmen.nl/patching-jax-rs-3/ to see how this can be done now (in Java EE 7 in JBoss for example).