# Patch method in Java

Tags: java, json, api, crud, patch

Well, i have this request in Postman:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/empleado/615050/retrieve-update/
```

and i add this body:

```
{"nombre":Marc}
```

this request working for me, in my API development in Django

but, when i try to replicate this request in my Java desktop app, fail and nothing happen. This is my Java code:

```
public void sendJson() {

        JsonObjectBuilder o = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        o.add("contrasenia", txtPass.getText());
        JsonObject contra = o.build();
        String contraS = contra.toString();
        System.out.println(contraS);
        
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8000/empleado/" + txtUsuario.getText() + "/retrieve-update/");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("PATCH");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(contraS.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            os.close();
   

        } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {
            malformedURLException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Ideas? thank, sorry for my English

Comment: The `JSON`-object you posted is not a valid `JSON`-object, `Marc` must be surrounded by `"`.

Comment: In development it can be useful to have an error catch-all like `catch (Exception e)` so you can print out if an unknown one occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, unfortunately, `PATCH` is not a legal verb for `HttpURLConnection`

See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod-java.lang.String-) for `HttpURLConnection#setRequestMethod`

```
Set the method for the URL request, one of:
GET
POST
HEAD
OPTIONS
PUT
DELETE
TRACE
are legal, subject to protocol restrictions. The default method is GET.
```

There are workarounds like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45912379/5050667) but your server should be compatible with the custom header.

I'd probably try to use a more advanced HTTP client if I were you

- [Feign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63580015/5050667)
- [OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28162219/5050667)
- [RESTEasy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253899/how-to-implement-patch-requests-in-resteasy/25257870)
- [Rest-assured](http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2019/12/03/rest-assured-tutorial-11-lets-write-first-patch-request-in-rest-assured/)

Or any other